# GitHub action docker bind mount not finding folder

Tags: docker, github-actions, docker-volume

I have a github workflow running on ubuntu:latest container.
I've installed docker on it, and want to run another container with bind mount.

```yaml
name Test
run: |
  docker run -d -i --name NAME  --mount type=bind,src="/tmp/scenarios",target="/data" --entrypoint /bin/bash myImage:$VERSION
  docker exec NAME ./test /data/myfile.csv
```

I've ran `ls /tmp/scenarios` and the files are there. I even ran `chmod -R 777 /tmp/scenarios` to make sure the permissions are set correctly.

However, the mount complains that the source folder does not exist.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a really annoying and undocumented restriction of GitHub Actions. In short, you just can't mount directories to a container you run unless it lives in certain directories.

Try putting the `scenarios` folder in `${{ runner.temp }}` and using it that way, for example:

```
name: Test
run: |
  mv /tmp/scenarios ${{ runner.temp }}/scenarios
  docker run -d -i --name NAME --mount type=bind,src="${{ runner.temp }}/scenarios",target="/data" --entrypoint /bin/bash myImage:$VERSION
  docker exec NAME ./test /data/myfile.csv
```